# Two panels side by side (one with TextCtrl) - wxPython

Tags: wxpython, panel

This is my code:

```
import wx #For graphics' interface
import os #For operating system compatibility


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):

        #SETUP
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, title = "MyTitle", size = (550,300))
        self.dirname=''

        #CREATE
        self.create_status_bar()
        self.create_menu_bar()
        self.create_text_panel()
        self.create_graphics_panel()

        self.SetAutoLayout(True)

        lc = wx.LayoutConstraints()
        lc.top.SameAs(self, wx.Top, 5)
        lc.left.SameAs(self, wx.Left, 5)
        lc.bottom.SameAs(self, wx.Bottom, 5)
        lc.right.PercentOf(self, wx.Right, 40)
        self.panelA.SetConstraints(lc)

        lc = wx.LayoutConstraints()
        lc.top.SameAs(self, wx.Top, 5)
        lc.left.RightOf(self.panelA, 5)
        lc.bottom.SameAs(self, wx.Bottom, 5)
        lc.right.SameAs(self, wx.Right, 5)
        self.panelB.SetConstraints(lc)


# FUNCTIONS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def create_status_bar(self):
        self.CreateStatusBar() #A Statusbar at the bottom of the window


    def create_menu_bar(self):

    # File Menu
        filemenu= wx.Menu()

        menuOpen = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, "&Open", "Open file to edit")
        filemenu.AppendSeparator()
        menuSave = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_SAVE, "&Save", "Save the file")
        menuSaveAs = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_SAVEAS, "Save &As", "Save the file with a new name")
        filemenu.AppendSeparator()
        menuExit = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "E&xit", "Terminate communication and close window")

    #The Menu Bar
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(filemenu,"&File") #Adding the "File" menu to the 'menuBar'
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)  #Adding the 'menuBar' to the Frame content

    #Event binding
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOpen, menuOpen)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, menuExit)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnSave, menuSave)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnSaveAs, menuSaveAs)


    def create_text_panel(self):
        self.panelA = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panelA.control = wx.TextCtrl(self.panelA, wx.ID_ANY, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE) #Text area with multiline
        self.panelA.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)


    def create_graphics_panel(self):
        self.panelB = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panelB.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLACK)


# EVENTS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnExit(self, event):
        self.Close(True) #Close the frame


    def OnOpen(self, event):
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file", self.dirname, "", "*.*", wx.OPEN)

        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.filename = dlg.GetFilename()
            self.dirname = dlg.GetDirectory()
            f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'r')
            self.panelA.control.SetValue(f.read())
            f.close()
        dlg.Destroy()


    def OnSave(self, event):
        f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'w')
        f.write(self.panelA.control.GetValue())
        f.close()


    def OnSaveAs(self, event):
        file_choices = "TXT (*.txt)|*.txt"
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, message = "Save file as...", defaultDir = os.getcwd(), defaultFile = self.filename, wildcard = file_choices, style = wx.SAVE)

        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            f = open(os.path.join(dlg.GetDirectory(), dlg.GetFilename()), 'w')
            f.write(self.panelA.control.GetValue())
            f.close()


# RUN!
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp(False)
    app.frame = MainWindow(None, wx.ID_ANY, "tSock - Adaptation Technologies")
    app.frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

My problem is that I can't seem to get it to work the way I want it.  I want to have two panels: the one on the left to work as a text editor and the other one on the right to receive input from the serial port (future work).

However, I can't seem to get the left panel to work properly.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Please bear with me as a noob: I'm nowhere near a programmer

Comment: Not sure what you want the left panel to look like, and your using LayoutConstraints which i never use, i use sizers but i do see that you have set no constraint for TextCtrl which might be what your missing.

Comment: I'm open to all possibilities.  If you feel sizers should be the way to go, please feel free to write an answer :)

Comment: @Yoriz I just used them because I found them in an example, not because I'm a hardcore lover of them.  Please teach me master!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a sizer to panelA and add the text control to the sizer so that it can expand and take up space appropriately:

```
import wx #For graphics' interface
import os #For operating system compatibility


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):

        #SETUP
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, title = "MyTitle", size = (550,300))
        self.dirname=''

        #CREATE
        self.create_status_bar()
        self.create_menu_bar()
        self.create_text_panel()
        self.create_graphics_panel()

        self.SetAutoLayout(True)

        lc = wx.LayoutConstraints()
        lc.top.SameAs(self, wx.Top, 5)
        lc.left.SameAs(self, wx.Left, 5)
        lc.bottom.SameAs(self, wx.Bottom, 5)
        lc.right.PercentOf(self, wx.Right, 40)
        self.panelA.SetConstraints(lc)

        lc = wx.LayoutConstraints()
        lc.top.SameAs(self, wx.Top, 5)
        lc.left.RightOf(self.panelA, 5)
        lc.bottom.SameAs(self, wx.Bottom, 5)
        lc.right.SameAs(self, wx.Right, 5)
        self.panelB.SetConstraints(lc)



# FUNCTIONS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def create_status_bar(self):
        self.CreateStatusBar() #A Statusbar at the bottom of the window


    def create_menu_bar(self):

    # File Menu
        filemenu= wx.Menu()

        menuOpen = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, "&Open", "Open file to edit")
        filemenu.AppendSeparator()
        menuSave = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_SAVE, "&Save", "Save the file")
        menuSaveAs = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_SAVEAS, "Save &As", "Save the file with a new name")
        filemenu.AppendSeparator()
        menuExit = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "E&xit", "Terminate communication and close window")

    #The Menu Bar
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(filemenu,"&File") #Adding the "File" menu to the 'menuBar'
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)  #Adding the 'menuBar' to the Frame content

    #Event binding
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOpen, menuOpen)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, menuExit)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnSave, menuSave)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnSaveAs, menuSaveAs)


    def create_text_panel(self):
        self.panelA = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panelA.control = wx.TextCtrl(self.panelA, wx.ID_ANY, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE) #Text area with multiline
        self.panelA.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)

        panelA_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        panelA_sizer.Add(self.panelA.control, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.panelA.SetSizer(panelA_sizer)


    def create_graphics_panel(self):
        self.panelB = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panelB.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLACK)



# EVENTS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnExit(self, event):
        self.Close(True) #Close the frame


    def OnOpen(self, event):
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file", self.dirname, "", "*.*", wx.OPEN)

        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.filename = dlg.GetFilename()
            self.dirname = dlg.GetDirectory()
            f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'r')
            self.panelA.control.SetValue(f.read())
            f.close()
        dlg.Destroy()


    def OnSave(self, event):
        f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'w')
        f.write(self.panelA.control.GetValue())
        f.close()


    def OnSaveAs(self, event):
        file_choices = "TXT (*.txt)|*.txt"
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, message = "Save file as...", defaultDir = os.getcwd(), defaultFile = self.filename, wildcard = file_choices, style = wx.SAVE)

        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            f = open(os.path.join(dlg.GetDirectory(), dlg.GetFilename()), 'w')
            f.write(self.panelA.control.GetValue())
            f.close()


# RUN!
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp(False)
    app.frame = MainWindow(None, wx.ID_ANY, "tSock - Adaptation Technologies")
    app.frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Also note that `wx.PySimpleApp` is deprecated. You should use `wx.App(False)` now. I would also recommend making a top level panel that the two other panels inherit from or perhaps use a splitter widget.

Here's how to use a top-level panel:

```
import wx #For graphics' interface
import os #For operating system compatibility


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):

        #SETUP
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, title = "MyTitle", size = (550,300))
        self.dirname=''

        self.top_panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        #CREATE
        self.create_status_bar()
        self.create_menu_bar()
        self.create_text_panel()
        self.create_graphics_panel()

        self.SetAutoLayout(True)

        lc = wx.LayoutConstraints()
        lc.top.SameAs(self, wx.Top, 5)
        lc.left.SameAs(self, wx.Left, 5)
        lc.bottom.SameAs(self, wx.Bottom, 5)
        lc.right.PercentOf(self, wx.Right, 40)
        self.panelA.SetConstraints(lc)

        lc = wx.LayoutConstraints()
        lc.top.SameAs(self, wx.Top, 5)
        lc.left.RightOf(self.panelA, 5)
        lc.bottom.SameAs(self, wx.Bottom, 5)
        lc.right.SameAs(self, wx.Right, 5)
        self.panelB.SetConstraints(lc)

        self.top_panel.SetSizer(self.main_sizer)


# FUNCTIONS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def create_status_bar(self):
        self.CreateStatusBar() #A Statusbar at the bottom of the window


    def create_menu_bar(self):

    # File Menu
        filemenu= wx.Menu()

        menuOpen = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, "&Open", "Open file to edit")
        filemenu.AppendSeparator()
        menuSave = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_SAVE, "&Save", "Save the file")
        menuSaveAs = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_SAVEAS, "Save &As", "Save the file with a new name")
        filemenu.AppendSeparator()
        menuExit = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "E&xit", "Terminate communication and close window")

    #The Menu Bar
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(filemenu,"&File") #Adding the "File" menu to the 'menuBar'
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)  #Adding the 'menuBar' to the Frame content

    #Event binding
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOpen, menuOpen)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, menuExit)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnSave, menuSave)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnSaveAs, menuSaveAs)


    def create_text_panel(self):
        self.panelA = wx.Panel(self.top_panel)
        self.panelA.control = wx.TextCtrl(self.panelA, wx.ID_ANY, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE) #Text area with multiline
        self.panelA.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)

        panelA_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        panelA_sizer.Add(self.panelA.control, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.panelA.SetSizer(panelA_sizer)
        self.main_sizer.Add(self.panelA, 1, wx.EXPAND)



    def create_graphics_panel(self):
        self.panelB = wx.Panel(self.top_panel)
        self.panelB.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLACK)
        self.main_sizer.Add(self.panelB, 1, wx.EXPAND)


# EVENTS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnExit(self, event):
        self.Close(True) #Close the frame


    def OnOpen(self, event):
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file", self.dirname, "", "*.*", wx.OPEN)

        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.filename = dlg.GetFilename()
            self.dirname = dlg.GetDirectory()
            f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'r')
            self.panelA.control.SetValue(f.read())
            f.close()
        dlg.Destroy()


    def OnSave(self, event):
        f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'w')
        f.write(self.panelA.control.GetValue())
        f.close()


    def OnSaveAs(self, event):
        file_choices = "TXT (*.txt)|*.txt"
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, message = "Save file as...", defaultDir = os.getcwd(), defaultFile = self.filename, wildcard = file_choices, style = wx.SAVE)

        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            f = open(os.path.join(dlg.GetDirectory(), dlg.GetFilename()), 'w')
            f.write(self.panelA.control.GetValue())
            f.close()


# RUN!
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp(False)
    app.frame = MainWindow(None, wx.ID_ANY, "tSock - Adaptation Technologies")
    app.frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Another approach, which I like the best, is to put each panel into its own class. I believe this gives you much more flexibility. Here's one way to do that:

```
import wx #For graphics' interface
import os #For operating system compatibility

class TextPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)

        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE) #Text area with multiline

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.control, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

class GraphicsPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLACK)


class TopPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        text = TextPanel(self)
        main_sizer.Add(text, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        graphics = GraphicsPanel(self)
        main_sizer.Add(graphics, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):

        #SETUP
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, title = "MyTitle", size = (550,300))
        self.dirname=''

        self.top_panel = TopPanel(self)

        #CREATE
        self.create_status_bar()
        self.create_menu_bar()


# FUNCTIONS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def create_status_bar(self):
        self.CreateStatusBar() #A Statusbar at the bottom of the window


    def create_menu_bar(self):

    # File Menu
        filemenu= wx.Menu()

        menuOpen = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, "&Open", "Open file to edit")
        filemenu.AppendSeparator()
        menuSave = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_SAVE, "&Save", "Save the file")
        menuSaveAs = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_SAVEAS, "Save &As", "Save the file with a new name")
        filemenu.AppendSeparator()
        menuExit = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "E&xit", "Terminate communication and close window")

    #The Menu Bar
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(filemenu,"&File") #Adding the "File" menu to the 'menuBar'
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)  #Adding the 'menuBar' to the Frame content

    #Event binding
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOpen, menuOpen)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, menuExit)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnSave, menuSave)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnSaveAs, menuSaveAs)

# EVENTS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnExit(self, event):
        self.Close(True) #Close the frame


    def OnOpen(self, event):
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file", self.dirname, "", "*.*", wx.OPEN)

        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.filename = dlg.GetFilename()
            self.dirname = dlg.GetDirectory()
            f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'r')
            self.panelA.control.SetValue(f.read())
            f.close()
        dlg.Destroy()


    def OnSave(self, event):
        f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'w')
        f.write(self.panelA.control.GetValue())
        f.close()


    def OnSaveAs(self, event):
        file_choices = "TXT (*.txt)|*.txt"
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, message = "Save file as...", defaultDir = os.getcwd(), defaultFile = self.filename, wildcard = file_choices, style = wx.SAVE)

        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            f = open(os.path.join(dlg.GetDirectory(), dlg.GetFilename()), 'w')
            f.write(self.panelA.control.GetValue())
            f.close()


# RUN!
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp(False)
    app.frame = MainWindow(None, wx.ID_ANY, "tSock - Adaptation Technologies")
    app.frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How do I do the top level panel?  should I go a new class?  How do I do that?

Comment: I added a couple more examples that might help you.

Comment: Yes!! I was looking how to do the third approach, since is what I came up to in the [Style Guide](http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPython%20Style%20Guide), but I had **no idea** how to do it.  Thank you so much, I'm learning a lot! :)

Comment: Just a follow-up question: how do I do to call the `OnOpen`, `OnSave` and `OnSaveAs` events?  should I use `self.top_panel.panelA.control`?

Comment: I would recommend using pubsub: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/09/05/wxpython-2-9-and-the-newer-pubsub-api-a-simple-tutorial/